# CakePHP - SQL Query to join 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have 3 tables

`News(id, year_id, month_id, title, description)` where year_id and month_id are foreign keys from tables

`years(id,...)` and

`months(id,...)`

respectively.

**2014** - 2015 - 2016 - 2017

**January**

- news title 1 (January 1, 2014)
- news title 2 (January 17, 2014)

**February**

- news title 1 (February 5, 2014)
- news title 2 (February 20, 2014)

As you can get an idea that first of all, i want to show all year's list(2013, 2014, 2015) and i did it successfully.

And now i want that below that list of years, the news must be displayed grouped according to months(e.g. all news of January month under "January" heading and so on till December of Year 2014 and below that, similarly complete set of all news according to months of Year 2015 and so on....)

I just want to know if there is any way to get required results from a SQL join or group by query
or i will have to manage this 100% using coding and by simply fetching all records from table without any query.

I have searched for this on google but not getting the solutions.

Need just a little idea regarding this.....

Comment: Why would you ever have separate tables with `month` and `year` IDs ?

Answer (score 0):

I may know nothing about `CakePHP` and I've been wondering why would you ever have separate tables with `month` and `year` ID's.. as I've asked in a comment which you didn't mind replying.

Anyway, if you want to keep your database structure, just use this :

```
SELECT 
    news.title,
    months.name,
    months.day,
    years.year 
FROM news 
JOIN months ON  months.id = news.month_id 
JOIN years ON years.id = news.year_id
ORDER BY
    months.month ASC,
    years.year ASC
```

I think this should do ( did not check obviously if there's any error but.. this is the idea ).
You cannot group since we're not using any `aggregate function`.

**To note that I just assumed the columns of `years` and `months` as I have no idea how did you name your other columns from those tables aside the `id` which I guess it's just an `index` but you can replace them as you wish**

Even though I suggest getting rid of your `months` and `years` tables and just store the month and year number if you really want to in the `News` table as you can always output a month's name in PHP.

Comment: Thank you @edduvs ....... i think better to go with one table instead of separate ones, got confused just and i have already tried these joins, but didn't get expected results. Thanx for help & sorry for delay..... :)

Comment: You need to modify it according to your table columns.

Comment: Yes @edduvs I have merged these three tables into one "news" table and have got the desired output without any joins bcoz therz just one table now. Thanku